# How to add additional signup attributes using AWS Cognito?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I'm trying to create a signup form using cognito and react and I currently have it working with just email and password required, but I'm wondering if I can have additional fields like first name and surname that the user can enter during the initial registration.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Using aws cli, you need to make sure you've CLI configured correctly.

--user-attributes Name="custom:countryOrigin",Value="United Kingdom"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/add-custom-attributes.html#examples

**Method 2**

- To add a custom attribute using the console
- From the navigation bar on the left choose Attributes.

  For each new attribute:
- Choose Add another attribute under Do you want to add custom
  attributes?.
- Choose the properties for each custom attribute, such as the data
  Type (string or number), the Name, Min length, and Max length.
- If you want to allow the user to change the value of a custom
  attribute after the value has been provided by the user, select
  Mutable.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html

Comment: I have all my desired attributes set up but I'm trying to figure out how to add them to the user pool once the user enters them into the field clicks register

Comment: whats the response?